# DynamoDB two sort keys with one as a date

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a primary key structure that is like this:

```
  
    PRODUCT_ID   EFFECTIVE_DATE   SUB_PRODUCT_ID
    1            19701231         1
    1            19701231         2
    1            19901231         1
    1            20081231         2
```

I would like to have this in DynamoDB, now I *think* the partition key of **PRODUCT_ID** makes sense and I *think* having the **EFFECTIVE_DATE** as the sort key makes sense.

i.e. if I wanted to see the active entry where **PRODUCT_ID** = 1 and **SUB_PRODUCT_ID** = 1  that was effective on 19851231 this should return me the top entry.

But I *think* I need **SUB_PRODUCT_ID** in the sort key as well, is that correct? The partition key and the sort key make up the primary key but these won't be unique without the **SUB_PRODUCT_ID**.

I would like the ability to query on the date so I'm not sure if I should concatenate the **EFFECTIVE_DATE** and the **SUB_PRODUCT_ID** into a compound sort key.

What is the right way to handle this?

Thank you all!